# Quantile regression power analysis

Tags: statistical-power, quantile-regression

New to the site and to stats here! This may be a silly question, but I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer on the procedure for a power analysis (or general guidelines about sample size) with a quantile regression. I plan on looking at 3 predictors along a single outcome. What would a recommended sample size be, or how can I conduct a power analysis? I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For general linear quantile models of the form
$$F^{-1}_{Y|X}(\tau) = X'\beta_n(\tau)$$
where $\beta_n$ is allowed to depend on the sample size, Chernozhukov and Fernandez-Val (2005) construct a power analysis for conditional quantile regression models as in your case. They consider the general null hypothesis
$$R(\tau)\beta_0 (\tau) - r(\tau) = 0$$
for $\tau \in (0,1)$. Their procedure allows you to test for

- a significant effect for a given predictor
- a constant effect for a given predictor across quantiles
- stochastic dominance (e.g. unanimously beneficial impact of a treatment)

Victor Chernozhukov makes his `R` code available on his [website](http://www.mit.edu/~vchern/) under the section "Policy Analysis" for the paper "Subsampling on Quantile Regression Processes".

**References**
Chernozhukov, V. and Fernandez-Val, I. (2005) "Subsampling on Quantile Regression Processes", The Indian Journal of Statistics, Special Issue on Quantile Regression and Related Methods, Vol. 67 part 2, pp. 253-276